# Any way to auto close Chrome when closing the last tab?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, stock-browser

I have been using the stock Android browser for several years and I am trying to make the switch over to Chrome.  The one major annoyance I have with Chrome is that the browser doesn't automatically close when I close the last tab like it does in the stock Android browser.  This may not seem like a big deal, but I tend to use a lot of apps that open web pages.  With the stock Android browser, closing the last web page will auto close the browser and return me back to the app I was using.  With Chrome, I have to manually close the browser or manually switch back to the app I was using.

Does anyone know how to make Chrome automatically close down when I close the last tab?  If not, is there another good browser that works this way?

Answer (score 1):

For **Dolphin** browser, use the phone MENU button and chose EXIT

For **Firefox**, install the `Quit Now` add-on and use the new QUIT button in the menu.

For any **other TAB browser**, close all TABs prior to push BACK in order to exit.

For any **persistently running browser**, use the task manager to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been a fan of Chrome. It lacks too many features compared to other browsers.

Anyway, most browsers support tabs and have an x symbol on the tab. Normally, the browsers remain open even if close all tabs. There is always 1 tab that remains open, and it won't close even if you click the x symbol. You'd have to click the back button to close the browser.

Among the browsers I use - about 4 of them - Maxthon behaves differently. It doesn't exactly do what you want, but if you click on the x symbol, it acts as a back button. So if there's only 1 tab open and you press it twice, it will exit the browser.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Chrome 39, it works out of the box. Just click the x close button on the tab and then browser quit.